# How is send a parameter to page object method and verify its existence?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, page-object-gem

Below is my page file . In my step definition I am trying to verify the availability of "linka" or "linkb"

```
class PageName
  include PageObject

  link(:linka, :text => 'texta')
  link(:linkb, :text => 'textb')

  def is_Available?(element)
    return element?
  end  

end
```

Below is the  ways I thought to achieve this. Here I am planning to send the variable name of the link that is declared in my page as a parameter. Expected **true** to be printed on console.

```
Then(/^I verify availability of "(.*?)"$/) do |arg1|
    puts on(HomePage).is_Available? arg1
end
```

Facing the below error

> ```
> Then I verify availability of "linka"
>   undefined method `element?' for #<HomePage:0x35b2300> (NoMethodError)
>   ./features/support/pages/HomePage_page.rb:12:in `is_Available?'
>   ./features/step_definitions/homepage.rb:8:in `/^I verify availability of " (.*?)"$/'
>   features\HomePage.feature:5:in `Then I verify availability of "reviews"'
> ```

May I know where I went wrong?

Suggest me some work around

Regards,
Avinash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `element` in the `is_Available?` method parameters is not the same as the `element?` that is returned. In the current code, the page object is looking for the method `element?` instead of `linka?` or `linkb?`.

To convert a string into a method call, you can use `send`:

```
def is_Available?(element)
  return send("#{element}?")
end
```

This method:

1. Takes the string passed in (eg "linka" or "linkb")
2. Adds a question mark to the end of the string - ie to create "linka?" or "linkb?"
3. Sends the page object a method call based on the string, which ultimately is like calling `page.linka?` or `page.linkb?`.